# How to loop through a HashSet<T> when it is provided as an object and the T can be anything?

Tags: c#, reflection, valueinjecter

I'm using Value Injecters to map from 1 type to another using the LoopValueInjection and overriding the SetValue(object v) method with some custom logic.  I am trying to detect when a HashSet is being passed in and go through the HashSet and apply a method to each item in it to do some clean up.  The issues I'm having are because the parameter is just an object and I don't know what the type of item will be in the HashSet.  For example, it could be HashSet or HashSet.

Here is the code I currently have but I'm getting an InvalidCastException.

```
    protected override object SetValue(object v)
    {
        if (type.Name == "HashSet`1")
        {
            var genericType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];

            // this line throws the InvalidCastException 
            var cleanHashSet = (HashSet<object>)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

            foreach (var item in (HashSet<object>)v)  // I'm sure this cast will throw as well
            {
                cleanHashSet.Add(Clean(item));
            }

            return cleanHashSet;
        }

        return base.SetValue(v);
    }
```

I guess the main question is how can I loop through the HashSet that is passed in as an object once I determine it is in fact a HashSet of some kind?  I'm also thinking I will need to create a new empty HashSet of the specific type as well so I can put each item that gets cleaned up into it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In .NET only interfaces and delegate types can be co- and contra-variant. So it is not possible to cast `HashSet<SomeType>` to `HashSet<object>`.

You want to cast your `v` to non-generic version of `IEnumerable` interface

```
dynamic cleanHashSet = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
foreach (object item in (IEnumerable)v)
{
    cleanHashSet.Add(Clean(item)); 
}
```

If you don't want to use `dynamic` keyword then you need to call `Add` method with reflection

```
object cleanHashSet = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var method = type.GetMethod("Add");
foreach (object item in (IEnumerable)v)
{
    method.Invoke(cleanHashSet, new object[] { Clean(item) });
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, didn't think about dynamic.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
bool isHashSet = typeof(HashSet<object>).IsAssignableFrom(type);
```

or

```
object x = ...
HashSet<object> hs = x as HashSet<object>;
if (hs != null)
{
    // use hs
}
```

If you really have `<T>` specified then use it instead of `object`.

---

`HashSet<T>` [implements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) `ICollection<T>`, `IEnumerabel<T>`, `IEnumerable`. What means if you know `T` you can both enumerate and add. Otherwise enumerate only enumerate.

Comment: @hazzik: Thanks. Fixed. As far as it's possible.